# regular expression which starts with "1", "10", "101" but not "11", "12", "102", "103" of numeric 11 digits long

Tags: jquery, regex

```
function validateregex() {
        var testreg = $("#txtregex").val();
        filter = /^1|10|101\d{0,8}$/;
        var regExp = new RegExp(filter);
        if (regExp.test(testreg)) {
            alert("valid");
        }
    }
```

first character - 1
first two characters - 10
first three characters - 101
example 10112345678

Comment: First character - "1" but not "2","3".....
Second Character - "10" but not "11", "12"....
Third character - "101" but not "102", "103"...

Expected result - 10123456789
But not - 11023456789

Comment: Uh... Why not just do `101\d{8}`?

Comment: So basically anything starting with 101 and 11 digits long is ok, but nothing else?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund: it can start with either 1, 10 or 101 but not other than these

Comment: @user3079691 so only 101???

Comment: @Lindrian: no that logic is not working

Comment: @user3079691 so provide any other example of 11 digits which not start with 101 which should still be valid following your logic. I'm lost!

Comment: please provide an example of input where `101\d{8}` doesn't work.

Comment: @A.Wolff: the intention is when we enter 1, 10, 101 till 11 digits it should not throw any alert error

Comment: @AlexShesterov: try entering 1 or 10 it doesn't work....but it works from 101

Comment: @vmx First character - "1" but not "2","3"..... Second Character - "10" but not "11", "12".... Third character - "101" but not "102", "103"... Expected result - 10123456789 But not - 11023456789 –

Comment: the problem is solve...you can unhold it, answer is ^(1(0(1\d{0,8})?)?)?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(1(0(1\d{0,8})?)?)?$
```

would do the trick.

Comment: No this will not solve the problem....try it check with "11" it accepts but it should not

Comment: ok, then add begin/end markers (`^` and `$`). i've updated the answer

Comment: What would be the scenario if I want to show it as valid till 101 and after entering 11 digits completely....in between of 101 and 11 digits I should show it as invalid

Comment: It cannot be done with regex alone. You need to change your validation function's behaviour (or the validation function itself) upon entering 11 valid digits. 
For example: if the regex above matches _and_ the length of input is 11, _or_ if the input field loses focus, then change the validation regex to `^101\d{8}$`. If length of input becomes zero, then change the regex back to `^(1(0(1\d{0,8})?)?)?$`.

Comment: ok thnx for the information